# The meaning of "this" in Typescript used as the parameter of a function

Tags: typescript

I saw a piece of TypeScript as below, "this" is used as the parameter of a function. What's the meaning? Why it is used like this way? ---- "brushended(this: SVGGElement) {".

```
function brushended(this: SVGGElement) {
  let e = <D3BrushEvent<any>>d3.event;
  let s: BrushSelection = e.selection;
  if (!s) {
    if (!idleTimeout) {
      self.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        idleTimeout = window.setTimeout(idled, idleDelay);
      });
      return idleTimeout;
    }
    x.domain(x0);
    y.domain(y0);
  } else {
    x.domain([s[0][0], s[1][0]].map(x.invert, x));
    y.domain([s[1][1], s[0][1]].map(y.invert, y));
    d3Svg.select<SVGGElement>('.brush').call(brush.move, null);
  }
  zoom();
}
```

Comment: It means what the [documentation says it does](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;**

It is a way for TypeScript to do static analysis when using `this.xxx` inside a function and to prevent executing a function that expects specific type on the `this` pointer. It does not have a representation in JavaScript.

**Longer version:**

As you might know, in JavaScript `this` can be a lot of different things depending on how the function is called. For example: you can use func.apply to choose which reference is put on the `this` pointer

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Take this TypeScript code for example:

```
function foo(this: string, n: number){
    console.log(this, n);
}
```

Here i specify that function `foo` should always be a executed with a `string` on the `this` pointer. This means that just calling results in a compiler error:

```
foo(42); // Error: The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'string'.
```

It is especially useful when interacting with frameworks that use the "feature" of the `this` pointer in JavaScript. For example: operators on an `Observable` in rxjs http://reactivex.io/rxjs/.

More information: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters